# how to get multidimensional array output

Tags: php

I have 3 arrays

```
$description[$cat_id][$kit_id][$item_id]  = $description ;
$description2[$cat_id][$kit_id][$item_id] = $description2 ;
$qty_total[$cat_id][$kit_id][$item_id]    = $qty;

foreach ($qty_total AS $key => $val) {
    echo "Cat: ".$key."<br />";
    foreach ($val AS $kkey => $kval) {
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;Kit: ".$kkey."<br />";
        foreach ($kval AS $ikey => $ival) {
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Item: ".$ikey." - ".$ival."<br />";      
        }
    }
}
```

This brings only `qty`.

My question is how to get `qty`, `description`, `description2` for given `[cat_id][kit_id][item_id]`?

Comment: Why are you putting them in separate arrays? Why not `$items[$cat_id][$kit_id][$item_id] = ["description" => $description, "description2" => $description2, "qty" => $qty];`

Comment: Also, it doesn't make sense for the array variable to be the same as the variable that you're using to set an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use keys of all `foreach()` loop to access other variables value

```
foreach ($qty_total AS $key => $val) {
    foreach ($val AS $kkey => $kval) {
        foreach ($kval AS $ikey => $ival) {
            echo $ival;
            echo PHP_EOL;
            echo $description2[$key][$kkey][$ikey];
            echo PHP_EOL;
            echo $description[$key][$kkey][$ikey];
        }
    }
}
```

***Sample output:*** https://3v4l.org/9uYfT